# Jaro distance in MMA

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, programming, string-manipulation

I'm trying to program Jaro distance as requested by  [this page](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Jaro_distance)  I've done the following code that works well for the next two pairs ("MARTHA", "MARHTA") and ("DIXON", "DICKSONX") but when I try with ("JELLYFISH", "SMELLYFISH") I get an error because the code counts the double S of "SMELLYFISH", due to this error I have not been able to finish successfully, here is what I have programmed up to this moment

```
uno = "DIXON"; dos ="DICKSONX" ;
rep = Characters[uno] \[Intersection] Characters[dos]
scope = Max[StringLength[uno], StringLength[dos]]/2 - 1
inter = Transpose[{Flatten[Position[Characters[uno], #] & /@ rep], 
   Flatten[Position[Characters[dos], #] & /@ rep]}]

m = Select[inter, Abs[#[[1]] - #[[2]]] < scope &]

prb = Select[m, #[[1]] != #[[2]] &]

trans = Length[DeleteCases[Position[prb, Reverse[#]] & /@ prb, {}]]/2

1/3 (Length[m]/StringLength[uno] + Length[m]/StringLength[dos] + (
   Length[m] - trans)/Length[m])

% // N
```

Someone who can help me solve this problem? Maybe the approach I'm using is wrong, I hope someone is interested in this problem too. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an alternative you can use `` Experimental`JaroDistance ``:

```
jD = Experimental`JaroDistance;
jD[uno, dos]
```

> 0.766667

```
jD["JELLYFISH", "SMELLYFISH"]
```

> 0.896296

Comment: thank you very much for the information has been very useful, since actually get the expected results, I did not know about that package, but I would like to performance my own version of that function, and check it with the option you proposed, I hope please You can help improve my programming attempt since you have more experience than me. Hoping to have your help, I say goodbye, wishing you an excellent day

Comment: Please, take a look at the solution proposed in the wolfram community, here is the link http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1416937 ,  I think it is very accurate, but I do not understand what the author of the answer is asking for, since he has already tried his function and fails, now I am trying to find the solution to the problem with the code he shared. Thanks for your help here on stack exchange, and vote for your answer